# Laravel - how to perform a where query on field through a relation?

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I've got a `Member` model which has a relation with one `User`:

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, "user_id");
    }
```

I need to perform a (filter) where query on fields within the user table. Here's my attempt using `with()` in my `MemberRepository`. What am I doing wrong and is there a better approach to this?

```php
$members = $this->model->where("id", $agencyId)->firstOrFail()->members();

$members->with(['users' => function ($members, $queryParam){
    $members->where('users.name', 'like', $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('users.surname', 'like', $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', $queryParam . '%');
}]);
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. Are you trying to fetch users? Or are you trying to fetch members and eager loading users? What is `$members` in this case (probably your repository instance, but how does it look)?

Comment: Hi Thomas. I'm trying to fetch members filtered by their name/surname/email from the user relation. Members looks like this:

 `$members = $this->model->where("id", $agencyId)->firstOrFail()->members();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, user model should be has an id field, if already has don't use secondly user_id field. If you are using user_id as primary key, please use:

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

I think different primary key is wrong way, right way is id.
So do not use, user_id in relations ....User::class, "user_id"...

Secondly, if you are not using with variable in your members model you have not use with method on eloquent query. And another mistake: with user not users

Your modified codes are below:

```
$members->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($queryParam) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('surname', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%');
});
```